# Go Fyne File Picker Dialog?

Tags: go, fyne

Is there a way to use the native file picker dialog when integrating with Fyne?

Currently, I am using the library implemented file picker, I would like to use the native look with the file path/address bar above the picker

```
showFilePicker := func() {
    fmt.Println("button tapped")
    onChosen := func(f fyne.URIReadCloser, err error) {
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        if f == nil {
            return
        }
        fmt.Printf("chosen: %v", f.URI())
        _ = uri.Set(f.URI().String())
    }
    dialog.ShowFileOpen(onChosen, w)
}
```

Comment: There was an issue for this 2 years ago but I'm not sure on the progress:
https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne/issues/225

Comment: "*would like to use the native look*" - I think that contradicts the concept of fyne to prefer consistency cross-platform. Are you missing certain features or is it just the looks?

Comment: I second this request. My macOS native file picker has lots of goodies, e.g saved paths in the sidebar. Having to navigate all those folders that is one click away natively seems painful.